# Comparing a JSON file and a PHP file

Tags: php, json

First Post, any help is appreciated.

I have a **PHP file** (Array) with data from a database, which i need to compare to a **JSON file** (Object).
By looking through forums i have seen stuff about **jQuery** and **AJAX** requests, so i was thinking maybe i need to use those for my solution.

**The PHP Array**

```
<?php 
$codes = [
[
    'code' => '1111',
    'name' => 'Management',
],
[
    'code' => '1305',
    'name' => 'Price',
],
[
    'code' => '1161',
    'name' => 'Service',
]
```

and the array goes on.

**The JSON Object**

```
[{"name":"Management","code":"1111","accountingArea":"3194","managerUsername":null},
{"name":"Storage","code":"9033","accountingArea":"3194","managerUsername":null}]
```

is the way the JSON Object is formatted.
For some reason it has no name, which i don't know if it's a problem, when it comes to comparing two different files.

The product will need to be a **PHP script** that tells the user which entries are missing in the other file.

***The only thing that needs to be compared are the codes.***

I have not done anything with JSON files yet and am quite new to PHP too.
So far i have only included both the files in my script file and don't know where to start things off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take JSON from file as string and use php `json_decode()` function that function will return a php array, then you can just make a foreach cicle and check the codes

Your code should be similar to this

```
<?php
    $codes = [
    [
        'code' => '1111',
        'name' => 'Management',
    ],
    [
        'code' => '1305',
        'name' => 'Price',
    ],
    [
        'code' => '1161',
        'name' => 'Service',
    ]];
    
    $json_str = '[{"name":"Management","code":"1111","accountingArea":"3194","managerUsername":null},
    {"name":"Management","code":"11141","accountingArea":"3194","managerUsername":null},
    {"name":"Management","code":"1305","accountingArea":"3194","managerUsername":null},
    {"name":"Management","code":"1161","accountingArea":"3194","managerUsername":null},
    {"name":"Storage","code":"9033","accountingArea":"3194","managerUsername":null}]';
    $json_array = json_decode($json_str, true);
    
    $result = array();
    $codesN = array_column($codes, 'code');
    
    $i = 0;
    for($i; $i < count($json_array); $i++) {
       if(in_array($json_array[$i]["code"], $codesN)) {
        $result[] = $json_array[$i]["code"];
       }
    }
    
    var_dump($result);
```

This will return:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "1111"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "1305"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "1161"
}
```

Comment: How are you doing `$json_array[$i]["code"] == $codes[$i]["code"]` While both arrays doesn't have the same length? You need to loop each code in json and compare it in all the codes in the `php` array

Comment: It depends on what he exatly wants to do, he can also foreach one of two arrays and make all the custom checks

Comment: This also doesn't work because `json_decode()` will decode to an object by default, and it wasn't explictly told to convert to an associative array.

Comment: @pavelbere have you tested the function above? you are comparing the arrays based on $i not based on code!!!! for example if the first code is 1 in json array and 1 exists on php array on number 4, you will have empty comparison and false result!

Comment: @Burhan Kashour I just suggest an idea of how could it work, I don't know what exactly author needs, obviously it's not a working solution, is someone want use it he should  adapt the code for specific case

Comment: @pavelbere I've tested the function, and to get it work I used `in_array`, see the [sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d045868ec7559941d9ee4bd5367e31370e68ba67)

Comment: I'm sorry to say, but @BurhanKashour is right. You should at least test your contribution when you provide it as an answer to somebody who is clearly new to things. The code didn't even run without a Warning.

Comment: I've edited the answer and update the json array to be longer

Answer (score 1):

Try this. See comments for step-by-step explanation.

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [1]=>
  string(4) "1305"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "1161"
}
```

Code:

```
<?php

// Your input array.
$codes = [
    [
        'code' => '1111',
        'name' => 'Management',
    ],
    [
        'code' => '1305',
        'name' => 'Price',
    ],
    [
        'code' => '1161',
        'name' => 'Service',
    ]
];

// Your input JSON.
$json = '[{"name":"Management","code":"1111","accountingArea":"3194","managerUsername":null},{"name":"Storage","code":"9033","accountingArea":"3194","managerUsername":null}]';

// Get differences:
// Get values from $codes that are not present in $json.
// Switch the arguments to perform the inverse comparison.
$diff = array_diff(
    array_column($codes, 'code'),
    array_column(json_decode($json, TRUE), 'code')
);

var_dump($diff);
/*
Output:
array(2) {
  [1]=>
  string(4) "1305"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "1161"
}
*/
```

Comment: Do I have to input the entire data from the 2 files in my new PHP file? Or can i work with require/inlcude?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your question. But if your input data (the array and the JSON) reside in different places, then you are free to import them using either `include()` or `require()`.